# How to parse city from this JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse the city from this JSON file

http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/airbnb.js

This is how I parse the other data and that works (that works!):

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/airbnb.js",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(results){
    var number_of_employees = results.number_of_employees;
    var founded_month = results.founded_month;
    var founded_year = results.founded_year;

    $('#number_of_employees').append(number_of_employees);
    $('#founded').append(founded_month + '/' + founded_year);

}
});
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
var location = results.city;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be multiple offices  but to get the first you'd access it this way:

```
var office_city = results.offices[0].city;
```

You'd probably want to check those fields actually exist... here's some more defensive programming:

```
if (typeof(results.offices) == 'object' && results.offices.length > 0 && results.offices[0].city)
{
  var office_city = results.offices[0].city;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `city` property directly on the object.

However, there is one located at `results.offices[0].city`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Q7CUD/).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
results.offices[0].city;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
results.offices[0].city;
```

will do the job

[image]